# How to change id font-size using jQuery .attr()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the font-size of an id using jQuery method .attr() as follows:

```
$("#level-title").attr("font-size", "1rem");
```

Which is not working.

This id is currently being installed in my external CSS like this:

```
#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 2%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}
```

How can I proprently change its font-size using jQuery?

My complete stylesheet can be seen here:

https://github.com/raschmitt/simon-game/blob/master/styles.css#L17

And my Js file here:

https://github.com/raschmitt/simon-game/blob/master/game.js#L48

Comment: There is no attribute as `font-size`, if you really need to use the attribute, you should use a `font` tag and the `size` attribute, something like this: `<font size="6">This is some text!</font>`. See [more](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_size.asp) .

Comment: you need to use .`css` not `attr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To manage the style of an element using jQuery you have to use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("#level-title").css("font-size", "1rem");
```

Though, not preferred, you can still use `attr()` by setting the *style* attribute:

```
$("#level-title").attr("style", "font-size: 1rem");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.css()`

`$("#level-title").css("font-size", "1rem");`